# jQuery bind method only gets called if you click the button twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, bind

I am building an application with Backbone.js on the front end. The user should be able to cancel a class by clicking the button with class ".btn-danger". The function works...but not until the button is clicked the second time. Nothing happens on the first click. I Think the problem has to do with the bind method being nested inside the "deleteItem" function but I am not sure.

```
events: {
    'click .btn-danger' : 'deleteItem'
},



deleteItem: function(event) {

    alert('deleting');
    var attrID = "";

    $('.btn-danger').bind('click', function() {

        var attrID = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(attrID);

         jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/test/signups/" + attrID, 
            type: "DELETE",

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
                console.log("Post response:"); 
                console.dir(data); 
                console.log(textStatus); 
                console.dir(jqXHR); 

            }
        });

    });
    event.preventDefault();

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this. First, your issue with bind on the `data-attribute` is that backbone binds the event methods' context to the view itself. So, you can access the clicked element through `event.currentTarget`, such as:

```
deleteItem: function(event) {
  var attrID = $(event.currentTarget).data('id');
  // ...
}
```

Another option would be to create a sub view for each item wherein you can use the data from the model itself. This could make things more complicated based on your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Your view uses two binding mechanisms :

1. the events hash provided by Backbone,
2. an explicit bind on `$('.btn-danger')`

The first one sets up the second, which means the handler can only be called on the second click (and that you're building multiple listeners for the same event). See this Fiddle to illustrate the phenomenon http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/EPppL/

Remove the binding done in `deleteItem` to handle events using Backbone :

```
deleteItem: function(event) {
    var attrID = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(attrID);

    jQuery.ajax({
        // ...
    });

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - your answer makes sense. But, when I remove the binding, I am no longer able to access each item by its individual "id". I am trying to delete these items by hooking into the ID and sending a delete request to the server. Without the bind I can only access the ID on the first element. Maybe I can do the binding in my initialize function..?